# Communication beet fragment and jetpack compose screen

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am using navigation component and single activity pattern. Now I am using jetpack compose inside  fragment with xml layout. I have integrate with library. The library for checking user card data. After launching library from fragment it override to method success and failed. Now I want to change from fragment composable screen state. How I can implement it. Here is my code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
class InstallmentFragment : Fragment(),ResultListener {

    private val viewModel: TrancheViewModel by viewModels()
    private val preferenceHelper by lazy { PreferenceHelper.defaultPreference(requireContext()) }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View { // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        requireActivity().window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)

        return ComposeView(requireActivity()).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                    AppTheme {
                        Navigation(SectionName.nasiyaMain.name)
                }
            }
            ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(rootView) { view, insent ->
                val bottom = insent.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()).bottom
                view.updatePadding(bottom = bottom)
                insent
            }
        }
    }

    
    
    override fun onError(e: Exception) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onSuccess(result: MyResult) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

I want to change composable screen content onSuccess function

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to fix your problem. the simplest way is using `mutableStateOf` as a property in `InstallmentFragment` and changing its value in `onResult` method.

I suggested seeing [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-state?index=..%2F..index#0).